# Tensorflow: How to host my own Embedding Projector?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, word-embedding

I would like to host this embedding projector in my own server, http://projector.tensorflow.org/.

But I couldn't find any guidelines on how can I fork this dashboard/UI so that I can use my own dataset to visualize using the same dashboard.

This is because I don't want to make the embedding projector public.

Is there a way to host this projector internally?

Thanks!

Comment: You might  fork the original embedding projector from this Github repo , modify and serve through Tensorflow  Serving  .  mentioning some examples and original repository below .                                                               
                                                                                
https://github.com/tensorflow/embedding-projector-standalone                                                    https://github.com/cnzeki/embedding-projector                                  https://github.com/harveyslash/TSNE-UMAP-Embedding-Visualisation

Comment: @TensorflowSupport thanks for this info! Appreciate it :)